# Featured Posts for Category Pages

Tags: posts, categories, query-posts

I was wondering if anyone knew how to have a different "featured post" based on it's category per category page? For example, if you are on the medical category page,  you would see a medical post featured in a special div and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assign the additional category 'featured' to the post in the category 'medical'.

in your category template, use a query with [`'category__and' => array(3, 27)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

example (assuming 'medical' is cat 3, and 'featured' is cat 27):

```
<?php $args = array(
  'category__and' => array(3, 27),
  'posts_per_page' => 1
  );
$feature = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $feature->have_posts() ) : while( $feature->have_posts() ) : $feature->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="featured">
   ANY POST OUTPUT <?php the_title(); ?>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```